# error sharing eclipse project in tfs

Tags: eclipse, tfs, windows-server-2008

I think I am missing something really silly here.  Recently our team began trying to integrate eclipse and TFS.  We are using the plug-in provided by microsoft for eclipse.  Everything seems to work fine as you go through the "share project" wizard but then it gives an error while it is adding the files to the server about the $TF folder.  It cites the full path with $TF ON THE SERVER and says to remove the $ from its name.

My understanding is that this folder should not be on the server.  Anyone have ideas on what may be the problem here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurred because the $TF folder was somehow created in the eclipse project.  The solution was to delete the folder and proceed.  It is important to choose the local workspace when sharing the project (and not the one on the server).